# How to use Keycloak with Flask REST API Service

Tags: flask, keycloak, flask-restful

I am trying to implement the Keycloak to my Flask Rest Service but it always gives below error.

{"error": "invalid_token", "error_description": "Token required but invalid"}

client_secrets.json

```
    {
    "web": {
        "issuer": "http://localhost:18080/auth/realms/Dev-Auth",
        "auth_uri": "http://localhost:18080/auth/realms/Dev-Auth/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
        "client_id": "flask_api",
        "client_secret": "0bff8456-9be2-4f82-884e-c7f9bea65bd1",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "http://localhost:5001/*"
        ],
        "userinfo_uri": "http://localhost:18080/auth/realms/Dev-Auth/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
        "token_uri": "http://localhost:18080/auth/realms/Dev-Auth/protocol/openid-connect/token",
        "token_introspection_uri": "http://localhost:18080/auth/realms/Dev-Auth/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
        "bearer_only": "true"
    } 
}
```

run.py

```
    import json
    import logging

    from flask import Flask, g, jsonify
    from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect
    import requests

    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.update({
        'SECRET_KEY': 'TESTING-ANURAG',
        'TESTING': True,
        'DEBUG': True,
        'OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS': 'client_secrets.json',
        'OIDC_OPENID_REALM': 'Dev-Auth',
        'OIDC_INTROSPECTION_AUTH_METHOD': 'bearer',
        'OIDC-SCOPES': ['openid']
    })


    oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)

@app.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
@oidc.accept_token(require_token=True, scopes_required=['openid'])
def hello_api():
    """OAuth 2.0 protected API endpoint accessible via AccessToken"""

    return json.dumps({'hello': 'Welcome %s' % g.oidc_token_info['sub']})


if __name__ == '__main__':
```

[image]

Anyone has an idea, if anything is wrong here.

Comment: Please check your flask log and add it to your question.

Comment: It is just throwing 401 error.

Comment: According to [source code of flask-oidc](https://github.com/mmarchetti/flask-oidc/blob/master/flask_oidc/__init__.py#L700), an error should be recorded by logger if you get the message, `Token required but invalid`.

Comment: I checked the Keycloak endpoint config and it shows 

token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported 
0 "private_key_jwt"
1 "client_secret_basic"
2 "client_secret_post"

But I am setting 
OIDC_INTROSPECTION_AUTH_METHOD: bearer

And giving me an authorization error.

Comment: Where do you check the endpoint config on Keycloak? I'm having similar issues. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use token returned after login. You may be using the auth_token which is different from token. I faced the same issue.

Comment: I am running keycloak in docker and python flask app locally. Can anybody tell how to register this app in keycloak. And what all settings to be done in keycloak?

Comment: Anyone seeing this in recent times, the keycloak urls no longer have the /auth/  part after the base url. See http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration (change url and `myrealm` to your options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and I (finally \o/) made it work. Try the following:

```
'OIDC_INTROSPECTION_AUTH_METHOD': 'client_secret_post'
'OIDC_TOKEN_TYPE_HINT': 'access_token'
```

Also remove the list of required scopes to avoid any possible error there:

```
@oidc.accept_token(require_token=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me - also including the scope: @oidc.accept_token(require_token=True, scopes_required=['openid'])

Comment: @dafero could you show us how you solved this issue?

Comment: @nimrod-maina you just need to add to app.config.update, 'OIDC_INTROSPECTION_AUTH_METHOD' and 'OIDC_TOKEN_TYPE_HINT' with he values I posted before. Use OP's code as a reference. Let me know if you a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access your Rest service like just going to:

http://127.0.0.1:5001/api

then it won't work, because there is no access token.

what you can do instead is to access http://127.0.0.1:5001/private  and call /api from inside passing the token in the header =)

```
  @app.route('/private')
  @oidc.require_login
  def hello_me():
    info = oidc.user_getinfo(['email', 'openid_id'])

    if user_id in oidc.credentials_store:

        try:
            from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials
            access_token = OAuth2Credentials.from_json(oidc.credentials_store[user_id]).access_token

            headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}

            access_like_this = requests.get('http://localhost:5001/api', headers=headers).text
        except:

            access_like_this = "we failed"

        return f'Hello, api: {access_like_this} <a href="/">Return</a>'

    else:

        return f'Ops, <a href="/">Return</a>'
```

Comment: Doing this gives an error 
`e.args[0].errno if isinstance(e.args[0], socket.error) else e.errno
IndexError: tuple index out of range`
which is occuring during the handling of another exception:

`File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/socks.py", line 718, in _negotiate_HTTP
    raise HTTPError(error)
socks.HTTPError: 403: Forbidden`

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://flask-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) says the following about accept_token decorator

> Tokens are accepted as part of the query URL (access_token value) or a POST form value (access_token).

So when you have something like

```
@app.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
@oidc.accept_token(require_token=True, scopes_required=['openid'])
def hello_api():
...
```

Your GET request should be

```
https://yourhost/api?access_token=blahblahsomethingquiteopaque
```

where **blahblahsomethingquiteopaque** is your OAUTH2 access token.

For POST api calls you have to provide access_token key/value in the data.

Here's an example from my project:

```
@app.route('/api/new_employee', methods=['POST'])
@oidc.accept_token(require_token=True)
def new_employee():
...
```

That API route is meant for submitting a form rendered by this view

```
from flask import Flask, g, redirect, request, Response, render_template
from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials

def auth(user):
user_id = user.get('sub')
username = user.get('preferred_username')
if user_id in oidc.credentials_store:
    access_token = OAuth2Credentials.from_json(oidc.credentials_store[user_id]).access_token
else:
    access_token = None
return username, access_token

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update({
    'SECRET_KEY': 'SomethingNotEntirelySecret',
    'TESTING': True,
    'DEBUG': True,
    'OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS': 'client_secrets.json',
    'OIDC_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE_SECURE': False,
    'OIDC_REQUIRE_VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
    'OIDC_USER_INFO_ENABLED': True,
    'OIDC_OPENID_REALM': 'flask-demo',
    'OIDC_SCOPES': ['openid', 'email', 'profile'],
    'OIDC_INTROSPECTION_AUTH_METHOD': 'client_secret_post',
})
oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)

@app.route('/grants/employees')
@oidc.require_login
def grants_employees():
    user = oidc.user_getinfo(['preferred_username', 'email', 'sub', 'groups'])
    vars['username'], vars['access_token'] = auth(user)
    if not vars['access_token']:
        oidc.logout()
        return redirect(request.url)
    return render_template('grants_employees.html', vars=vars)
```

And then in the grants_employees.html template inside form I have a hidden field with access token passed in vars['access_token']

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="inputAccessToken" name="access_token" value="{{ vars.access_token }}" required>
```

It's also worth mentioning that the docs say

> Note that this only works if a token introspection url is configured, as that URL will be queried for the validity and scopes of a token.

So you have to make sure that your client_secrets.json contains correct value for token_introspection_uri

```
{
    "web": {
        "issuer": "https://yourkeycloak/auth/realms/master",
        "auth_uri": "https://yourkeycloak/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
        "client_id": "your_client_id",
        "client_secret": "your_client_secret",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "http://127.0.0.1/*"
        ],
        "userinfo_uri": "https://yourkeycloak/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo", 
        "token_uri": "https://yourkeycloak/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token",
        "token_introspection_uri": "https://yourkeycloak/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flask_oidc doesn't work with the latest Flask version which is at the moment 2.1.2, the issue is that the latest Flask requires a itsdangerous package with the version 2 or above, the flask_oidc is not compatible any more with the latest itsdangerous package. I wasted a lot of time trying to get the flask_oidc work.

Comment: Oh yes, that's not funny. :(  did you manage to get it work without using flask-oidc?